# UICollectionView didSelectItem Not Called

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I use a simple Navigation Controller with a Collection View added on top of it using IB.  I declare the delegate and datasource for the collection view in the header, and wire it up in IB for the same.  The collection view populates with all the images, and will scroll, but didSelectItemAtIndexPath is never called.  What is going on?

Sorry, forgot to copy in the code before I clicked Submit.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];

     arryData = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"AIMCON", @"Devotional Songs", @"Saved Devotionals", @"Resources", @"Podcasts", @"Website", @"Links",  nil];
    CALayer * l = [viewofimage layer];
    [l setMasksToBounds:YES];
    [l setCornerRadius:11];
    [l setBorderWidth:2.0];
    [l setBorderColor:[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
    tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);

    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        [self.collectionView registerClass:[CVCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cvCell"];

        self.collectionView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    }
    else {
        [self.collectionView registerClass:[CVCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cvCell"];

        self.collectionView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    }


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}





-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {
    return 1;
    NSLog(@"1");
}
-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [arryData count];
    NSLog(@"2");
}

-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSLog(@"Selected");
    if (indexPath.row == 1) {
        DevoSongs *dvController = [[DevoSongs alloc] initWithNibName:@"DevoSongs" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

        [self.navigationController pushViewController:dvController animated:YES];
        [dvController release];
    }
    if (indexPath.row == 2) {
        ListOfDevos *dvController7 = [[ListOfDevos alloc] initWithNibName:@"ListOfDevos" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

        [self.navigationController pushViewController:dvController7 animated:YES];
        [dvController7 release];

    }
    if (indexPath.row == 3) {
        AIMProject *dvController7 = [[AIMProject alloc] initWithNibName:@"AIMProject" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

        [self.navigationController pushViewController:dvController7 animated:YES];
        [dvController7 release];

    }
    if (indexPath.row == 4) {
        Podcasts *dvController2 = [[Podcasts alloc] initWithNibName:@"Podcasts" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

        [self.navigationController pushViewController:dvController2 animated:YES];
        [dvController2 release];

    }
    if (indexPath.row == 5) {
        FamilyMinistry *dvController5 = [[FamilyMinistry alloc] initWithNibName:@"FamilyMinistry" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

        [self.navigationController pushViewController:dvController5 animated:YES];
        [dvController5 release];

    }
    if (indexPath.row == 6) {
        LinksViewController *dvController6 = [[LinksViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LinksViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

        [self.navigationController pushViewController:dvController6 animated:YES];
        [dvController6 release];
    }

    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        NSLog(@"TABLE");
        SECTable *dvController7 = [[SECTable alloc] initWithNibName:@"SECTable" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:dvController7 animated:YES];
        [dvController7 release];
    }

}
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {



    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cvCell";

    CVCell *cell = (CVCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];


    NSString *thearticleImage = [[arryData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] stringByAppendingString:@".png"];
    [cell.theimage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:thearticleImage]];
    //titleLabel2.text = entry.articleTitle;

    CALayer * l = [cell.theimage layer];
    [l setMasksToBounds:YES];
     [l setCornerRadius:11];
    [l setBorderWidth:2.0];
    [l setBorderColor:[[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor]];
    [cell.labels setText:[arryData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Please provide code that you have done for collection view @user717452

Comment: My bad, @Sachin.  got it in now

Comment: @user717452, where are you writing these lines `self.collectionView.delegate = self` ? If you didn't set your `collectionView.delegate`, then the function will not be called

Comment: I have it wired up in IB for the delegate, thinking that was all that needed...added it into viewDidLoad and that worked, thanks @KrishnaCA

Comment: @user717452, I wrote it as an answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, the issue happened due to not setting `delegate` for the `collectionView`. Adding the line

```
self.collectionView.delegate = self
```

resolves the issue

Comment: @jbnunn, You need to set the `delegate` of `UICollectionView` to the class where you are implementing the function, otherwise the functions will not be called. That can be done in the storyboard itself or we can do it in code